# Symfony2 - Managing routes involving 2 kinds of bundle

Tags: symfony

I am a beginner in Symfony2, and I am working on Symfony2 project in which a kind of general bundle, let say CoreBundle, is managing all the routes (in this form, first.domain/a-route, second.domain/a-route, third.domain/a-route,...) of the website. Now I have been creating FirstBundle, SecondBundle, ThirdBundle with the idea to "transfer" the management of routes of each subdomain (firt, second, third,...) to the related bundle.

Beginning with the transfer of routes from CoreBundle to FirstBundle by editing /app/config/routing.yml file from:

```
resource: "@ProjectFirstBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"

    prefix: /

host: "{subdomain}.{domain}"

    defaults: { _controller: ProjectFirstBundle:Public:aroute }

      domain: %project_domain%

    requirements:

      domain: "%project_domain%"

      subdomain:  'first'
```

to:

```
resource: "@ProjectFirstBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"

    prefix: /
```

And then creating FirstBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml file with the following content:

```
project_first_aroute:

    path:    /a-route

    host: "{subdomain}.{domain}"

    defaults: { _controller: ProjectFirstBundle:Public:aroute }

      domain: %project_domain%

    requirements:

      domain: "%project_domain%"

      subdomain:  'first'
```

And of course I have created controller and view files using the same schema as CoreBundle (by making an adaptation -- inheritance for .twig files). As the result, the following exception is being returned when running first.domain/a-route:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException' with message 'Unable to parse at line 15 (near " domain: %project_domain%").' in

Any suggestions as to how I can effectively achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Came to find out that I should have created FirstBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml file as followed:

project_first_aroute:

```
path:    /a-route

host: "{subdomain}.{domain}"

defaults: { _controller: ProjectFirstBundle:Public:aroute, domain: "%project_domain%" }      

requirements:

  domain: "%project_domain%"

  subdomain:  'first'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a **syntax error from** the **Yaml** Parser.

Please note that correct idention is essential in a Yaml File and check if you need to wrap `%project_domain` in quotes on the first occurence (see stackoverflow syntax highlighting, it looks odd).

-

**Debugging routes in Symfony2**

`app/console router:debug`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've checked carefully my indentation and used quotes on %project_domain%, but still getting the same exception. Sometimes the real problem is not what is stated in the exception; the exception may only give a remote clue to identifying the issue.

Comment: Well yes, but not with a parser error. It **must** have something to do with the Yaml File *imo*.

Comment: Anyway do you know the command ```app/console router:debug```? Please post the output of that.

Comment: This is what I get from the command router:debug
  [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]
  Cannot import resource "C:\my_root\my-platform\src\Project\FirstBundle/Resour
  ces/config/routing.yml" from "C:/my_root/my-platform/app/config\routing.yml". (
  Unable to parse at line 15 (near "    domain: "%cv_domain%"").)






  [Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException]
  Unable to parse at line 15 (near "    domain: "%project_domain%"").



router:debug [--show-controllers] [--format="..."] [--raw] [name]